# SQLCop procs cause warnings in SSDT projects due to improper casing

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcop

FYI: Posting this here since I'm unable to register at LessThanDot.  Not sure if it's our company firewall (wouldn't be surprised!)

I'm starting to use SQL Cop as part of quality control for a new project.  I keep all its procs in a SSDT project.  I've noticed that, although the project builds correctly, it flags many statements with warnings due to casing differences. An example would be

```
[SQLCop].[test Old Backups]
...
    Select  @Output = @Output + 'Outdated Backup For '+ D.Name + Char(13) + Char(10)
    FROM    master..sysdatabases As D         
            Left Join msdb.dbo.backupset As B             
              On  B.database_name = D.Name
```

Of course this works just fine, since master is set as case insensitive, however the sysdatabases view uses lower-case for the columns returned.  When you build a SSDT project with these procs, build flags e.g. "Name" as a case mismatch.

You can disable case checking in the SSDT project, but I'd rather see SQLCop conform to the casing used by SQL Server for the columns of its system views and functions.

A secondary issue with this same query is

```
FROM    master..sysdatabases As D
```

Again, this works just fine because of the way SQL Server resolves system views, but it is flagged by SSDT since an omitted schema implies dbo and sysdatabases is in the sys schema, at least since SQL Server 2005.

Perhaps a greater concern is that sysdatabases is deprecated.  IIUC sys.databases may be the replacement.

Hoping that George is still listening on this channel!

Comment: It cannot "conform to the casing used by SQL Server" because the collation used by `master` is the server default collation, which is configurable at install time. It therefore takes the safe path and assumes the collation being used on the operational server *might* be a case-sensitive one. Such code can actually *fail* on servers that do use a case-sensitive collation, so determine for yourself if that's something you want to be concerned about. (In general, it would be far too much effort to replicate all possible collation rules inside SSDT, so even *this* is simplified.)

Comment: With my version of SSDT (15.8.1), referencing the `master.dacpac` for SQL Server 2017, I cannot replicate the `master..sysdatabases` issue -- no warning is produced either by SSDT itself or Code Analysis. Due to the way name resolution on the old system objects works, just plain `sysdatabases` will resolve too. But yes, where possible, you should get rid of uses of the deprecated system tables (now views on those tables) -- they've been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 and they lack support for newer features, so there's no real excuse for still clinging to them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  It should use lower-case names, since the dmvs in question return lower-case names.  to your point, SQLCop may fail as it is since it uses upper case names.  I cannot see any reason why SQLCop's use of "Name" with a capital is preferable to what the dmv actually returns ("name" with no cap)

Comment: Wow, ouch, my bad. I assumed (we all know how bad assumptions are...) that you used "SQLCop" as a shorthand for "SSDT Code Analysis", in the same way FXCop was the name of the standalone tool that did static analysis for .NET before it was integrated in VS and named Code Analysis (and StyleCop still exists separately for syntax enforcement). But apparently that's not the case; SQLCop has nothing to do with Code Analysis and isn't made by Microsoft at all. So everything I said is irrelevant: I don't know anything about how SQLCop works. Obviously, though, it should leave `master` alone!

Comment: My recommendation would be to actually activate Code Analysis on the SSDT project (the analysis bits that *are* made by Microsoft), and see if that does anything for you, in lieu of a  tool that apparently hasn't seen updates in 10 years. There are probably things SQLCop checks and Code Analysis does not (and vice versa) but at least Code Analysis is fully cognizant of the system databases.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I gave that a try.  All it did is rebuild the solution.  No evidence that it analyzed anything and no results produced other than successful build.  I know that there are violations of the rules it checks, but it didn't flag anything.  What I did was enable code analysis in the project and rebuild.  I guess it's not fully operational.